# Swagger integration with Inversifyjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, swagger-ui

Any one help me with that giving any one of Rest API example?

Create One Example of Node Rest API using Inversifyjs ,typescript and Expressjs.
And Integrate Swagger documentations.

I have tried with normal express route with creating swagger.json but it is not working.